# 'share shops' in the Netherlands

Tags: netherlands, shopping, terminology

I have heard of these so-called 'share shops' in the Netherlands whereby for a small contribution of an item (not specified), you are able to join a library and borrow, for a short time, an item you need.

Does anyone know what these shops are really called? I'd like to travel to see them myself with a view to setting one up in Scotland.

Comment: There are multiple initiatives like this in the Netherlands, however I have not heard of a physical shop. Most of these "deelwinkels" are online on existing platforms like facebook. How did you hear about these share shops?

Comment: I am a native Dutch citizen and have never of these shops, so they are probably not that common :)

Comment: Thanks Bart and Bernhard. I heard about them at a talk by Robin McAlpine, who works with the Reid Foundation in Scotland. I did a little more research and I think it's maybe online site, Peerby, that I might be looking for. Cheers for your responses though ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Give-away shops ("weggeefwinkels") are quite different from what you're describing but they might suit your needs very well. [Here](http://weggeefwinkels.nl/adreslijst/) is a list.

[This article](http://geldloos.nl/spullen-delen) has extensive information about sharing stuff in the Netherlands. It's in Dutch but translates well through Google Translate.